# What is stored in a boolean variable in Java ? (as per the memory, bit patterns)

Tags: java, boolean

I googled it and I found that it is virtual machine dependent. But still in what ways ?

Comment: something above 2.3 volts for TTL arch...

Comment: Not at that level, a more abstract answer would be fine.Boolean variable is of 2 bytes in some VM, so a justification of that would be more than enough. Thank you.

Comment: The Java spec makes no guarantees about anything like this. What JVM are you interested in? Hotspot?

Comment: In C, I used to create my own boolean types `typedef int bool` by defining 1 as true and 0 as false. So I think here is the same and it changes depending on the arch.

Comment: Sun Microsystems.

Comment: @ShOm So... Yes to HotSpot? It's owned by Oracle now.

Comment: Yes that will also be fine @Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**boolean type will be converted to int**

There are no Java Virtual Machine instructions solely dedicated to operations on boolean values. Instead, expressions in the Java programming language that operate on boolean values are compiled to use values of the Java Virtual Machine int data type.

You can read more in [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4)